# alternative for pyhook in linux?

Tags: python

i want to know whether there exists an alternative for pyhook(available for windows not on linux) for linux to hook messages.

Comment: Instant duplicate of [pyhook in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177925/pyhook-in-linux), though this version is more precise and does not mention keyloggers directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't needed but I have seen

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/

Comment: i had already downloaded it i wanted to know does any alternative exists ?