# Capturing keyboard input in python as a daemon in Linux

Tags: python, linux, input, keyboard, daemon

I wanted to know if there were any python modules that allow access to keyboard interrupts non-disruptively. I wanted to make a text-to-speech program, perhaps for the blind programmer out there, and wanted to know how to grab key-presses in real time. There exists things like pyHook for Windows, but what do I use for Linux? Ideally I should be able to get the events such as KB_UP in Windows.

I like orca, but I wanted to design a text-to-speech myself better suited to my needs. If such a thing does not exist for python, what language should I choose to implement such a program? I have heard of pyGame for keyboard input, but I want my program to incur minimal overhead and work in the background.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [pyhook in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177925/pyhook-in-linux). But that was closed without an accepted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [alternative for pyhook in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178191/alternative-for-pyhook-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual for linux, there are a variety of different interfaces that can do different parts of what you want on different systems.

I'm guessing what you want is a way to talk to the `/dev/input/*` interfaces. You can do that just by opening them and `ioctl`ing and reading from them, but you probably don't want to do that.

[`evdev`](https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev) looks like a nice wrapper around both `/dev/input/*` and the `uinput` APIs.

Of you could grab [`pykeylogger`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/) and hack up the source to do what you want.